# How to display HTML tags as plain text

Tags: php, html

I have an input form on my website where HTML is allowed and I'm trying to add instructions about the use of HTML tags. I'd like the text to

```
<strong>Look just like this line - so then know how to type it</strong>
```

But so far all I get is:

**Look just like this line - so then know how to type it**

How can I show the tags so people know what to type?

Answer (score 372, accepted):

Replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.

Comment: *Technically* you only need to replace < by &lt; for it to be recognized by most browsers, but the > by &gt; is good practice

Comment: @Darm -1 for not mentioning htmlspecialchars(). If there's a justified reason for that please correct me :)

Comment: If the question's text were to be generated by PHP, [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) does what this answer suggests: replace the [less-than and greater-than signs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068951/what-do-entities-lt-and-gt-stand-for) (and others) with their [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/Entity). But the question does not specify, so this more general answer is a superset of all the PHP-specific answers. And the question is really about HTML.

Comment: In contrary of the other comments this answer saves me 100%, some of the answers I found in here would say just use php and **echo "<? //like this ?>";** but that didn't help at all still not showing. On the other hand this answer saves me 17 characters in total plus @handle has a point so voted up.

Answer (score 258):

In PHP use the function [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)() to escape `<` and `>`.

```
htmlspecialchars('<strong>something</strong>')
```

Answer (score 76):

As many others have said, `htmlentities()` will do the trick... but it will look like shit.

Wrap it up with a `<pre>` tag and you'll preserve your indentation.

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars($YOUR_HTML);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 43):

You should use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). It replaces characters as below:

- `&` (ampersand) becomes `&amp;`
- `"` (double quote) becomes `&quot;` when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
- `'` (single quote) becomes `&#039;` only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
- `<` (less than) becomes `&lt;`
- `>` (greater than) becomes `&gt;`

Answer (score 13):

you may use htmlspecialchars()

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

You just need to encode the `<>`s:

```
&lt;strong&gt;Look just like this line - so then know how to type it&lt;/strong&gt;
```

Answer (score 6):

To display HTML tags within a browser, surround the output with < xmp> and < / xmp> tags

Comment: `<xmp`> is obsolete now, more than just deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: A quick Google search on W3C reveals that XMP was introduced for displaying preformatted text in HTML 3.2 and earlier. When W3C deprecated the XMP tag, it suggested using the PRE tag as a preferred alternative.

Update: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#xmp, http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html#SEC5.5.2.1

share  edit  follow  flag

Answer (score 4):

You can use htmlentities when echoing to the browser, this will show the tag rather than have html interpret it.

See here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Example:

```
 echo htmlentities("<strong>Look just like this line - so then know how to type it</strong>");
```

Output:

```
<strong>Look just like this line - so then know how to type it</strong>
```

Answer (score 3):

> The native JavaScript approach -

```
('<strong>Look just ...</strong>').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

> Enjoy!

Comment: JavaScript isn't tagged in this post.

Comment: Thank you. It's usefull for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to convert characters that would otherwise be displayed as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way...

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

This makes the whole page served as plain text... better is htmlspecialchars...

Hope this helps...