# Print less-than and greater-than symbols in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am have troubles trying to print out `<` `>` symbols in HTML using PHP.

I am appending a string "`<machine>`" to a variable.

Example:

```
$output .= " <machine> ";
echo $output;
```

I tried using escapes, but that didn't help. Any advice?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php -- `echo htmlentities($output);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display HTML tags as plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Answer (score 27):

`&gt;` = `>`
`&lt;` = `<`

Or you can use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

```
$output .= htmlspecialchars(" <machine> ");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help along with everyone else who responded.

Comment: Or just `htmlspecialchars()` for the `echo` output only, no need to run it before then.

Comment: @Wesley: The OP's code included a concatenate so I wanted to stress it could still be used the same as their original intent (and that it returns a value, not just outputs one). But you are right, only need to call it at the top-most level.

Comment: just wanted to let you know 4+ years down the line, you helped another person :P

Answer (score 9):

If you are outputting HTML, you cannot just use **`<`** and **`>`** : you must use the corresponding [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) : **`&lt;`** and **`&gt;`**

If you have a string in PHP and want to automatically replace those characters by the corresponding HTML entities, you'll be interested by the [**`htmlspecialchars()`**](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) function *(quoting)* :

> The translations performed are:
>
> - `'&'` (ampersand) becomes `'&amp;'`
> - `'"'` (double quote) becomes `'&quot;'` when `ENT_NOQUOTES` is not
>     set.
> - `"'"` (single quote) becomes `'&#039;'` only when `ENT_QUOTES` is
>     set.
> - `'<'` (less than) becomes `'&lt;'`
> - `'>'` (greater than) becomes `'&gt;'`

In your case, a portion of code like this one :

$output = "  ";

```
echo htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Would get you the following HTML code as output :

```
 &lt;machine&gt;
```

And, just in case, if you want to encode more characters, you should take a look at the [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

Your trouble is not with PHP, but rather with the fact that `<` and `>` are used in HTML. If you want them to display in the browser, you probably want to print out their escaped entity versions:

- `<` is `&lt;`
- `>` is `&gt;`

You can also use the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to automatically convert them:

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<machine>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn them into e.g. `&lt;` and `&gt;` - see the `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo htmlentities($output);
```

or

```
echo htmlspecialchars($output);
```

If you don't want to  bother manually going through your string and replacing the entities.

Answer (score 0):

use "htmlspecialchars_decode()"

e.g.

```
<?php 
$a= htmlspecialchars('<?php ');
$a=$a.htmlspecialchars('echo shell_exec("ipconfig"); ');
$a=$a.htmlspecialchars('?>');

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($a);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The < and > symbols should be shown in the HTML source but the "<machine>" is interpreted as XML tag. Use htmlentities() to convert all special characters in the String into their HTML-equivalents, or use "&lt;machine&gt;"

**Solution:**

```
$output .= " <machine> ";
$output = htmlentites($output);
echo $output;
```