# PHP- allow and display < and > that are PART OF a String, currently hides anything inside < and >

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and web programming. I am working with an email message system, and messages are displayed with HTML formatting. All works well, except that what if someone sends an email that contains text inside < >? How do I say- Read tags as tags when they contain HTML code, but anything inside quotation marks change to `&lt;` and `&gt;` ?

Or- any easy way to restrict typing OR pasting those chars in a text area?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP string doesn't allow < and > characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207029/php-string-doesnt-allow-and-characters)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to be selective about when to render a "<"/">" as the literal character, and when to allow them as part of an HTML tag is challenging, and I would suggest it is something to avoid as much as possible.

I would recommend disallowing your users from inserting their own HTML markup within your emails, which would then allow you to use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to convert all characters into their corresponding entity so that they can be displayed.

If you are set on letting your users style content, then maybe look at using something like [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), so that they are not writing actual HTML code (as that opens a can of worms), but instead use a set of shorthand characters to indicate different basic styling to be applied programmatically using a parser like [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/)

Comment: My task is to add the styling. The email system now functions with no html, and it strips html using htmlspecialchars; what I did was removed that (and used htmlpurifier to prevent xss) and it works well except for just these characters: < and >. I would restrict the textarea to prevent typing or pasting those characters, but that only takes care of sending messages. What if it's receiving a message? It's very common to paste info like an email address for instance inside <>

Comment: As I said, letting users write actual HTML is opening a can of worms. Using Markdown (like Stackoverflow does) abstracts the HTML tags and means that ensuring that people are not leaving unclosed tags, etc. If HTMLPurifier is doing most of the job, and it is only cases where an email address is included between two angle brackets, maybe writing a piece of code to pre-process that and replace them with their HTML entities may work. Like `$content = preg_replace( '/<([^@]+@[^@]+)>/' , '&lt;$1&gt;' , $content );` . And run the content through that before HTMLPurifier.