# php echoing html break

Tags: php, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display HTML tags as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)
>   [Print less-than and greater-than symbols in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916023/print-less-than-and-greater-than-symbols-in-php)

How do I echo `<br />`?  When I echo, it makes a break in html file, but what I want is PHP code to write `"<br />"`

When I write:

```
echo "<br />";
```

it makes a break line in HTML. I want to see `<br />` as a text in the html page.

Comment: You're wanting `<br/>` to print visually on the page in the browser? [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: There are lots of people here willing to help -- being hostile or passive-aggressive is not really going to encourage them!

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

try [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo htmlentities("<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate sequence to escape the alligator mouths:

```
 echo "&lt;br /&gt;";
```

However, this would become tedious and unwieldy if you decide to handle other tags similarly. Consider [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and possibly [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) instead, and eliminate errors that would eventually creep in if you manually handled several eventualities. As a happy side effect, this will also make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

you should use something like this: `echo htmlspecialchars("put you code here");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to encode the html then output this to the browser.

```
echo htmlentities("<br />");
```