# How can i mark string as quoted in plain text email?

Tags: php, email, network-programming, email-parsing

How can i mark some parts of the email to be quoted i.e. to appear in email clients like gmail as 'older messages' in a mail conversation?

I'm sending mail with PHPMailer class and i tried adding the `>` before every new line, but it didn't work, in my test gmail rendered that normally.

Comment: You can try using `&gt;` so if you're echoing `echo "&gt; Text...";` which works.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, but that does not make _any_ sense. Please read the question and understand what is asked.

Comment: How such "marks" are displayed by one or another email client is up to the clients, there is no defined syntax or rule for this. Try using an additional space, if that does not work then use this attempt as always when trying to find a difference: dump a working and a not working example into a text file and compare them closely. What is the difference?

Comment: @arkascha I might have *somewhat* misunderstood the question, but the fact remains that PHP will (mis)interpret the `>` character.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please cite a reference explaining why php might suddenly start to interpret a `>` inside a string?

Comment: Yeah, i'm not echoing anything, i am creating a string that will be sent as email, so unfortunately &gt; doesn't work, because it's not being echoed into HTML - string is being created for email protocols. I was wondering if there was some defined rule for this in email protocols.

Comment: @IanDess The `echo` was an example.

Comment: @arkascha With the rep points you have, I think you should know that by now. I don't need to cite anything; it's a "known" fact.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah i understand that, but just tried it, it doesn't work, &gt; is just a HTML entity, it has nothing to do with email plain text :)

Comment: @IanDess You would need to provide some form of example code in order for others (*including myself*) to better understand what exactly it is we're dealing with and how you're trying to implement it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Looks like I am too much a bloody beginner and I really would be honored if you could share your wisdom. Apart from the 'bit shift operator' or a comparision I do not see any situation where php should interpret a `>` and this certainly not inside a string... Most likely I simply don't have enough practice in php. I never claimed you "have to cite" anything. I friendly asked you for it.

Comment: @arkascha Have a look at the Q&A's here => http://stackoverflow.com/q/6916023/ I'm sure I could find more, but that one came up in the TOP 5 when Googling "greater than > symbol in php misinterpreted". I'm "friendly" too ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- unfortunately the code is irrelevant here, it can be done in any server-side language, this question is more about email protocols and decoding/encoding messages in a way that mail servers can interpret them in a way i want. And i want to include quoted (older emails/emails from the thread) in a mail that i am sending. I'm afraid that we need someone with good knowledge of email standards and protocols to answer this. Hope this made it more clear :)

Comment: @IanDess Thanks for the clarification and you're right on finding someone with a good knowledge of email standards etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, but that explanation you cite _has nothing to do_ with the situation at hand. That is clear from the description and was already pointed out to you above in an explicit manner by the OP. This is _not_ about html. Apart from that: even _if_ html would be involved here it would _not_ be php that misinterprets that character. It would be the html side and it would be an interpretation, not a misinterpretation.

Comment: @arkascha In this situation, you're right. OP has made it a bit clearer for me.