# ASCII printable characters not displaying in posts

Tags: php, wordpress, post, ascii

I am running a wordpress site where users must insert descriptions for their posts and am experiencing a problem when calling the submitted data in php.

For example:
A user submits a post and their description includes some characters like ("), (,) (<), (>), (?) etc.

When the post is viewed after submission, the posts does not contain these characters, in fact, sometimes the entire description is ignored and does not display.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Check within database that these characters are gets stored or not? If not use `addslashes` function.

Comment: I think wordpress is removing them because of security reasons. All those symbols are common in many programming languages and dangerous for injections.

Comment: so if my code looks something like: `<?php echo $description; ?>` how would i add the `addslashes` function @Suraj

Comment: @RyanBest I'm not sure what problem you are facing? These characters does not display at all or what. I hope this links will help you.  Check your encoding in `wp-config.php` file as well It should be `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');` `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916023/print-less-than-and-greater-than-symbols-in-php

Comment: Use prepared statements to store the description and  `html_entities($description)` to display them on page.