# display data into html table which have special character

Tags: php

Deat All, How do i display data into a html table if my data have like the below:

$str=<table border='1' width='100px'><tr><td>30-00463-00P12><CARDS PENGUIN PICK &ldquo;UP&rdquo; HALVES &DOUBLES PK 18><VEST, &ldquo;RELEASABLE&rdquo; PACK, &lsquo;MD&rsquo;, WC W/ ARM</td></tr></table>

I want to display data into a table like "30-00473-03 MAGNETS GEOMAG 216 PIECES GEO76> are misssing.and it does noty print after <> ..i want diaply all character with this special character..Hope you got ..what i want ??

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print less-than and greater-than symbols in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916023/print-less-than-and-greater-than-symbols-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **htmlentities()** function in PHP as follows,

```
echo htmlentities($str);
```

it will automatically replace special characters by the corresponding HTML entities.

** For more info - [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: it gives the output like <table border='1' width='100px'><tr><td>30-00463-00P12><CARDS PENGUIN PICK &amp;ldquo;UP&amp;rdquo; HALVES &DOUBLES PK 18><VEST, &amp;ldquo;RELEASABLE&amp;rdquo; PACK, &amp;lsquo;MD&amp;rsquo;, WC W/ ARM</td></tr></table>...but want it display into table

Comment: Do you want a table cell which includes the text,    "30-00463-00P12><CARDS PENGUIN PICK “UP” HALVES &DOUBLES PK 18><VEST, “RELEASABLE” PACK, ‘MD’, WC W/ ARM" ??