# Error reading file extracted from tesseract using fopen PHP

Tags: php, tesseract

I'm using `fopen` in PHP to open a file extracted from tesseract OCR. The returned text contains `<<<<<<`, `fopen` reads till it finds the first `<` character then stops.

File returned from OCR:

```
P<dsdasdasd<<dasd<adsda<dsada<<<<<<<<<<ec<
dasdasdsdasdasdasdasd<<<<<<<<<<<<<<06

£ y
```

The echo from `fopen`:

```
P
```

If I view source, I found rest text in red color.

Code I used:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("tmpFile.jpg",file_get_contents("1.jpg"));
$cmd = "tesseract tmpFile.jpg ee ";
exec($cmd);
$myfile = fopen("ee.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$data= fread($myfile,100000000);
fclose($myfile);
echo $data;
?>
```

I paste the text in question and it also hidden.

Screenshot while I typing question and the text hidden in question:

[image]

Screen-shot from output and viewsource:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the issue has nothing to do with tesseract or your input text file.

> `fopen` reads till it finds the first < character then stops

I don't think that's true. Why would you see the rest of the source in "view source", then? `fopen` reads the whole file but the issue is with displaying that information in your browser.

You want to display characters which are reserved for HTML tags - in this case a `<` ("less than" symbol). That's why you get red text in "view source" since the browser doesn't know how to interpret the HTML code.

As a first workaround, just put a `<textarea>` tag around your `<?php` to view the data:

```
<textarea><?php
/* ...
your regular code here
... */
?></textarea>
```

The next step should be to encode those special characters before you give them to `echo`. Have a look at [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
or [`htmlentities`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.htmlentities.php).

You might also find useful information on the topic at:

- [Print less-than and greater-than symbols in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916023/print-less-than-and-greater-than-symbols-in-php)
- [How to display HTML tags as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Guess you should use `htmlentities` so you can safely display any data.