# How to render tags as html in browser

Tags: html, tags, rendering

How can I render these tags as html in a browser say for e.g. chrome?

```
<testname=tar_tests.sh>
    <description>
        Test basic functionality of `tar` command.
    <\description>
    <test_location>
        ltp/testcases/commands/tar/tar_tests.sh
    <\test_location>
<\testname>

<testname=unzip>
    <description>
        Test basic functionality of `unzip` command.

    <\description>
    <test_location>
        ltp/testcases/commands/unzip
    <\test_location>
<\testname>
```

Output:

```
<testname=tar_tests.sh> <description> Test basic functionality of `tar` command. <\description> <test_location> ltp/testcases/commands/tar/tar_tests.sh <\test_location> <\testname> <testname=unzip> <description> Test basic functionality of `unzip` command. <\description> <test_location> ltp/testcases/commands/unzip <\test_location> <\testname>
```

Comment: Your XML is malformed! Is it intentional?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Unless it's not XML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display HTML tags as plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use HTML entities for the brackets. Change `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`

Comment: Still looks quite ugly and unreadable. I added the output above. How can I get it to look nice and readable?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `<` and `>` characters as `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

So, in your HTML, in order to show:

```
<testname=tar_tests.sh>
```

You should write:

```
&lt;testname=tar_tests.sh&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the text in `<pre>`...`</pre>` it will be formatted  and you don't need to change all the tags into HTML entities. Whitespace and layout is preserved.

```
<pre>
&lt;testname=tar_tests.sh>
...
</pre>
```

Comment: @MrLister: Now that I have, I've updated the answer. `<pre>` is the right way to preserve layout. And you don't *need* to change `>` characters if you don't want to (although it is probably safest to do so).