# How do you show HTML code in source format?

Tags: html

We have some HTML code, which we would like to show in raw source format when the user clicks a certain link on the browser. How do we prevent the link contents to be interpreted by the HTML browser?

I am trying to use the same HTML file to render as well as shown in the source format.

Comment: Change its content-type to text/plain

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text

Comment: @RickKuipers - Doesn't work for IE prior to IE9, since IE <= 8 sniffs the content for HTML and thinks it knows better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suffice

```
<textarea rows=10 cols=50 readonly="true">
    <h1> Hello </h1>
    <emphasis> World </emphasis>
</textarea>
```

Comment: I am trying to use the same HTML file to render as well as show in the source format. But by doing this it would not be possible, correct?

Comment: This format will allow you to both render elements in the HTML file and allow you to show the code within a textarea.  Check this fiddle for more info http://jsfiddle.net/vp6jT/1/

Comment: Just a gentle reminder to tick the answer if you found it satisfactory

Comment: Your code seems to have been replicated twice (one for HTML, one for text area). I would prefer not to do that, is there an easier way, something like a wrapper.

Comment: That is simply to demonstrate that rendering elements and showing HTML code can be done in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this using JavaScript;

**[SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)**

Hope this helps.