# Display "<script src='some.js'></script>" in Html document

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show my users how they can embed my widget on their websites.For that I need to show something like above on the Html page but when I try to do that,it just loads my widget in that page where I put the above code.

Comment: As per the downvote `[title]` text, "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display HTML tags as plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Comment: Stackoverflow made it work in your question title.  Just view the source of this page and see how stackoverflow did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
&lt;script src="some.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

In general to use special characters in HTML you replace them with [named character references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Introduction#Named_character_references).

Comment: I need to escape characters.Is it the only way?

Comment: @RajatSaxena yeah. If you use php you could do `echo htmlspecialchars( '<script src="some.js"></script>', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @RajatSaxena - If you don't like writing out HTML Character Entities, you could use JavaScript: `document.getElementById("embedCode").appendChild(document.createTextNode("<script src=\"some.js\"><\/script>"));` (making sure to escape the slash in the script end tag, lest the HTML parser interpret it as the *actual* script end tag).  But, I wouldn't bother with that... What's wrong with HTML Character Entities?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [html entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

You have to write `&lt;script& src='some.js'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use entities for the special characters to prevent them from beeing parsed. Something like this

```
&lt;script src='some.js'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

As a sidenote, may i suggest you have a look at the `<code>` tag, a usefull thing to display code on a webpage. It will not prevent you from having to convert to entities, but it helps with your formatting (uses a monospaced font by default but can be styled to your wishes) and is great for SEO.

Comment: it won't do the trick indeed, not what i meant eather. But it is good practice to use them in this case, as it will display text in a monospaced font and improves your SEO

Comment: Perhaps you should revise your answer then.