# How can I escape from HTML while using echo?

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display HTML tags as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

```
echo "<b>test</b>";
```

I want to echo this exactly what I write.

```
<b>test</b>
```

Not a bold test.

How can I do that?

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars("<b>test</b>")` or `echo htmlentities("<b>test</b>")`

Comment: @SomeKittens how is this related ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty simple, just use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<b>test</b>");
```

[htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) will have the same effect, but its output will be slightly different in some cases - see the docs for details.

Comment: Thanks to you, i will tick this 6 minutes later.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<b>test</b>");
```

[Docs](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Answer (score 4):

You can escape an individual chunk of text by using [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<b>test</b>");
```

You can escape all forms of output by turning on output buffering with [ob_start](http://www.php.net/ob_start)() and telling php to run all output through a callback function

```
ob_start('htmlspecialchars');
echo "<b>test1</b>";
echo "<b>test2</b>";
ob_end_flush(); //ends buffering and sends the escaped output
```

You can also tell the browser the document is text, not html

```
header('content-type: text/plain');
echo "<b>test1</b>";
echo "<b>test2</b>";
```