# How to echo a new line which has <

Tags: echo

I want to echo a line 
which has the following:

```
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDyzCCAzSgAwIBAgIJAKRtpjsIvek1MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGgMQswCQYD
```

I tried

```
echo <^<ca>^>
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You have three main options:

- `echo \<ca\>` — escape special characters with backslash
- `echo '<ca>'` — enclose string in single quotes
- `echo "<ca>"` — enclose string in double quotes

If the line is stored in a variable, then only the third way (double quotes) works:

```
line="<ca>"   # Could be written three ways
echo "$line"  # The old-fashioned safe way (preserves spacing if there are spaces)
echo  $line   # The new-fashioned unsafe way, IMNSHO
```

The 'new-fashioned' way will be safe in that the angle brackets won't be interpreted as I/O redirections.  It's unsafe in that it loses spacing.  I strongly recommend using double quotes always; it will work<sup>*</sup>.

```
$ line="<  aa  bb  cc  >"
$ echo "$line"
<  aa  bb  cc  >
$
```

---

<sup>* Those who say the double quotes are unnecessary are referring to contexts like `[[ ... ]]` conditionals.  I'd rather not deal with unnecessary special cases; using double quotes works correctly in that context too, so I don't spend the time remembering when I can safely omit double quotes — double quotes always work, so I always use them.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try using single-quotes:

```
echo '<ca>'
```

Comment: Double quotes would also work, but single quotes are better in that they prevent anything in between from being interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

This work out for me:

```
<?php
$str=htmlspecialchars("<ca>");
$str.="\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
$str.="MIIDyzCCAzSgAwIBAgIJAKRtpjsIvek1MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGgMQswCQYD\n";
echo nl2br($str);
?>
```

Are you trying to write to file or only display on screen?

Comment: Ref. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use echo command for this. You can use it with single quotes or double quotes

```
echo "<ca>";
```