# how can we get raw html from mysql database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, iframe

I have a table in database. this table has one field which consist raw html data below format:

```
<iframe width="475" height="271" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GcUYa4_1aYs?rel=0&amp;hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

when I am fetching the data from database its rendering the html code. I want to just show as it is(Raw html) in PHP without rendering. how can i display it? when i am showing that, its just rendering the data from database.

Comment: Put it inside a `<pre></pre>`?

Comment: try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or use single quote `''`, this is a very good [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) on difference in php between single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlentities($your_html_code);`
It is your safest bet, it does what htmlspecialchars() does, and more.