# Show client-side HTML from div as plaintext

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a div containing some PHP processed HTML.

Like jsfiddle.net, i want d div, showing the HTML created from PHP, nested in another div. It is a program creating HTML/CSS, viewable to the client and now i want to make them able to copy the HTML/CSS codes for them to use.

The code and the viewable code will be on the same site.

Example:

```html
<div id="processed_html">
    <div id="item" style="color:black; width:154px;"></div>
    <div id="item" style="color:yellow; width:34px;"></div>
</div>

<div id="view_processed_client_code">
    //Here i want all the code above to show as plain text 
</div>
```

I have searched the web and haven´t been able to find any solution..

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: #emmanuel - I will, thanks

Comment: #j08691 - My mistake, just wierd to write in the snippit editor, here.. But thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display HTML tags as plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Comment: Could by, but i needed the code, not the setup. I got my help.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```js
// references to the element holding the client-entered code:
var processed = document.getElementById('processed_html'),
// and the area to which it should be output:
    output = document.getElementById('view_processed_client_code'),
// finding the text-property of the browser:
    textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

// setting the textual content of the output element to the innerHTML of the
// element holding the client-entered code:
output[textProp] = processed.innerHTML;
```

```css
#view_processed_client_code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="processed_html">
    <div class="item" style="color:black; width:154px;"></div>
    <div class="item" style="color:yellow; width:34px;"></div>
</div>

<div id="view_processed_client_code">
    //Here i want all the code above to show as plain text 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my project, so far!

Thanks again! :-)

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! :)