# stop html from database affecting other elements on web page

Tags: php, mysql

I have data in a *`MySQL`* table i am displaying on a *`PHP`* web page using a simple *`SQL`* select query. Its working fine and showing the data correctly with its HTML formatting from the database.

Its however, affecting other `HTML` elements on the web page because of the HTML being echoed from the database, how can i still echo the database data with its HTML formatting but stop it changing the styles of other hard coded elements?

Comment: please show/post your code, so that we can check and correct it.

Comment: You just want the html being printed out? Use frames? Or do you want to print the html as text?

Comment: i want to print as text

Answer (score 2):

We don't know all the circumstances here, but this is one of the reasons you should try to avoid storing html in a database. You basically have <strike>three</strike> four options here:

- Refactor your database logic, store only data and generate HTML on-the-fly.
- Use frames as suggested in one of the comments (won't remove existing styles but stops affecting other HTML you may have on the page).
- Use some-kind of HTML/DOM parsing library and try to remove all style related HTML attributes.
- If you need only text content you can check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: +1 I'd use the first and the forth option together to create a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the html as text, you could use htmlspecialchars:

```
htmlspecialchars('<strong>something</strong>')
```

See this answer for more information: [How to display HTML tags as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Comment: i dont want to show the HTML text - i want to show the correct formatting but because the data that is being returned from the database has HTML tags in and CSS, it is affecting other elements on the page

Comment: Put an example in your question, it will clear up a few things. Because you asked to print the html as text in your comment.

Comment: so the data that is being inserted into the database looks like: http://pastebin.com/isRJy7MS - i want to display it as HTML (as it is) but not to affect other elements on the same page

Comment: @user2710234 Do you have control of the text 'before' it is entered to the DB?

Comment: yes i do but i want to be able to keep the HTML there