# Why Html form input not accepting "<" character

Tags: php, html, post

I am a beginner in html/php.

I am trying to send a POST request to a php page but the values are not correctly posting

Input : `#include<iostream.h>`

Output : `#include`

`<iostream.h>` is not printing(echo) on php page

Html File

```
<form action="genPdf.php" method="POST">
    <input  type="text" name="text"></input>
    <input type="submit"  value="Click"></input>
</form>
```

genPdf.php

```
<?php
$data=$_POST["text"];
echo $data;
?>
```

The html file is posting data correctly(can see it in developers tools->Network)
but the php page is not printing complete text

Please do help
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text - this will help

Comment: where is name in your input type???

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$data=$_POST["text"];
$data=htmlspecialchars($data);
echo $data;
}
?>
```

You need to encode the coming data from input using htmlspecialchars();

Comment: if you have too many inputs than you should make a function and use it like this 
$data=validate($_POST["text"]);
$data2=validate($_POST["text2"]);

function validate($ci){
$ci = htmlspecialhars($ci);
$ci = trim($ci);
}

Comment: *"Validation"* and *escaping/encoding* are two different things really. You're not validating here, you're encoding.

Answer (score 1):

`<` and `>` are special characters in html - they make something into a tag. eg `<p>` so you won't see them if you try to echo them into the page (if you right-click and view source, you will probably see it in the page). If you want them to be visible, you'll need to use the html special chars: `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead