# Angular directive rendering HTML mark up, how can I stop it?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular directive:

```
<some-dir text="{{characterDescription}}"></some-dir> 


app.directive('someDir', function() {

    "use strict";

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
       // replace: true,
        template: '<p></p>',
        scope: {
            text: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem) {

            elem.append(scope.text);
        }
    };
});
```

The text which is passed into it looks like this:

```
{
    characterDescription : <b>tall</b>
}
```

At the moment, it's rendering the HTML, so I'm seeing **tall**, but I want it to treat HTML as plain text, so I want to see `<b>tall</b>`.

Is there an angular way of accomplishing this in my directive?

Comment: look at example here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Comment: Have you tried  elem.text(scope.text)? 

This will not interpret the string as HTML, but as a string purely.

http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

Comment: If I understood your question, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)  may help.

Comment: @pcagica that did the trick!! If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elem.text(sometext)
```

This will not interpret the string as HTML, as you can see in the doc's.
[jQuery.text() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2)

Comment: Worth adding just realized you could do it directly in the template, then you leverage angulars data-binding. `template: '<p>{{text}}</p>'` See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1dL16fof/1/

Comment: You're right, there are others options, like get the attribute value from the element, instead of passing it to directive scope. It only depends on what he wants to do with the directive.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
elem.text(scope.text);
```

Here's working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1dL16fof/

And docs: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

---

EDIT beat to answer in comments.

Comment: Still very much appreciated