# How can i use tags as text in HTML?

Tags: html

How may i use tag script in p tag?
For example:

```
<p>If u want to bind your js script to html file,u should enter <script src ='//path' type="text/javascript"></script></p>
```

It trying to read this, but i want in as guide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML tags as plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in few ways:

Let's assume you have `p` tag with `id='target'`

1. (**preferred**) Inject script by using DOM manipulation:

   ```
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
   s.setAttribute('src', '//path');
   document.getElementById('target').appendChild(s);
   ```
2. Simply insert your `script` tag with code below:

   ```
   document.getElementById('target').innertHTML = "<script src ='//path' type="text/javascript"><\/script>";
   ```