# php dosent echo the right value of a input

Tags: php, jquery

I want to concat a string in jquery, but when I post the string I see only a part of the mystringg.

My html is:

```
 <input type="text" style="display:none" name="mystring" id="mystring" value=""/>
```

I have some variables:

```
var ti="ti";
var low="low";
var moderate="moderate";
var high="high";
var title="title";
```

And I try to concat a string like:

```
var mystringg="";
mystringg+= "<\n"+ti+">";
mystringg+= "\n<LOW> "+low+" </LOW> ";
mystringg+= "\n<MODERATE> "+moderate+" </MODERATE> ";
mystringg+= "\n<HIGH> "+high+" </HIGH> ";
mystringg+="\n</"+title+">";

alert(mystringg); // here print the right value of the string
$('#mystring').val(mystringg);
```

In php:

```
$string  = $_POST['mystring'];
echo $string;
```

When I alert mystringg, I get the right string. 
But when I post it in an another php page, I only get a part of the value, actually I get only the value of the variables, not the manual values.

Comment: what is type of your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the full values.  The reason you don't think so is because you've wrapped them in tags, although not standard HTML tags.

If you `var_dump($_POST['mystring']);`, you'll see this:

`string '<ti><LOW> low </LOW> <MODERATE> moderate </MODERATE> <HIGH> high </HIGH> </title>'`

So, the full value is there.

But - when you view the `echo` of it (as your code does), the tags are being rendered as HTML tags (and thus don't show up), so it looks like this:

`low moderate high`

BUT, if you view source, you'll see that in fact it's all there:

```
<ti><LOW> low </LOW> 
<MODERATE> moderate </MODERATE> 
<HIGH> high </HIGH> 
</title>
```

If you want to see the "tags" when you echo them, then echo using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) like so:

```
echo htmlspecialchars( $_POST['mystring'] );
```

Comment: when I do this I get a message string(260) " ...." 0 . I have removed the tags and indeed the tags are the problem. Is there any other solution besides the var_dumb that is not working?

Comment: I found this: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text and the rendered is done. Thank you for your time