# JQuery append filters out html like tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, web, jquery-append

I would like to append below line of text to the select html tag using JQuery:

`"<option selected=true value="-1"><new></option>"`

The problem is in `<new>`. This substring is filtered out completely by `append` function. I know this is not legal html tag, and probably it filters it just of this reason. Can I force JQuery somehow to interpret `<new>` as substring? Because `<new>` is not meant as html tag, but only to point out to the user that this is not the value in the list, but a selection to make a new entry on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this post :
[How to display HTML tags as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

it shows you how to print special characters like < and > in between your code.

you should replace  `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test').append($('<option>').attr('value', -1).text('<new>')[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('<option/>').attr("value","-1").text("<new>").appendTo("select");
```

Thanks !