# Is there any alternative for <xml>, <pre>, <code> or escaping HTML tags to display HTML tags on a web page for a typing game program?

Tags: javascript, php, html, tags

I am working on a typing test for programming codes. The problem that is encountered is that everything works fine for other code aside from HTML and JavaScript and as you can guess, it is because of the behavior of browser to parse those codes even if enclosed with those.

The thing is, the source codes are coming from client-side and I display it with `htmlentities`. After that, I use javascript for highlighting, timer, accuracy and wpm. Now the problem is that the `<html>`, `<body>`, `<head>` and `<script>` are not showing in text whereas the other tags are showing as text. I tried the xml method and sometimes it doesn't work. As for the `<pre>` and `<code>` tag, they don't work at all. For escaping the HTML tags, I prove it quite impossible to use on my program since it is a typing game. For example if I used escaping method, `<` will be `&lt;` and I don't want my user to type `&lt;` just to get `<` right. As for making the area a textarea, I cannot do that since my program highlights the next character to be typed.

Would anyone be able to give me an insight on how to solve the problem? I could also post some source code but I'll only do so if needed.

EDIT: I am quite aware of possible duplicates but as far as I am concerned, my case is pretty different. I want to display the HTML codes without escaping/replacing characters. If I did so, it'll break the concept of the game where I need to type "<" just to get "<" right.

Comment: Did you try to work with strings and Replace the & character with &amp;
Replace the < character with &lt;
Replace the > character with &gt;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML tags as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Comment: yeah, I already tried replacing but as far as what I wanted to do, replacing < to &lt; will make my typing game not working as intended.

Comment: Typing a character, and displaying that character somewhere, are two completely different things. _“I am quite aware of possible duplicates but as far as I am concerned, my case is pretty”_ - no, it’s not. _“I want to display the HTML codes without escaping/replacing characters.”_ - that is a “requirement” that makes zero sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can try this, not sure this can help

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var text = output.textContent;
input.addEventListener('input', function(e){  
  var inputText = input.value.toString();
  var copy = text.substr(0, inputText.length);
  var lastText = '';
  for(var j=copy.length;j<text.length;j++){        
    lastText+=text[j];
  } 
  if (inputText == copy){      
      output.innerHTML = '<span class="blue" id="span"></span><span id="newoutput"></span>'
      var newoutput = document.getElementById('newoutput');
      var span = document.getElementById('span');
      newoutput.textContent = lastText;
      span.textContent = copy
   }
     
})
```

```css
#input{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  resize: none;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
#output{
  width: 400px;
}
#span{
   width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">&ltscript&gt some script &lt/script&gt</div>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
```

Comment: This actually works but quite different with how I'm doing. Here's the UI of the code I'm working with and as you could see, the tags are already loaded on screen and I need to match it character by character in the text area below. I appreciate the help though since I'm a new contributor as well. Thanks for this. See this screen shot here https://prnt.sc/pmlfhn

Comment: I have edit the snippet, you may try it, this is not the best way to do this, but the idea

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea since I was parsing the codes back and forth and having js render it is a really bad idea. My solution is to get the data from database, add span tags before rendering it on the screen vs what I did before where I got the data, displayed it, get the contents and add span tags via javascript then put it on display again.

Answer (score 0):

Writing  in the HTML File:

```
  <script>

  var y="<head>";

  $('#customDiv').text(y);

</script>
```

You can put a custom `<div id="customDiv"></div>` inside your html file.