# How to show span tag using pre tag without css

Tags: html, pre

I need to show this entire text in an HTML page:

```
<span class='per-amount' role='text' aria-label='1,496 undefineds'><span class='per-curr'>₪</span><span class='per-minus-sign'></span><span class='per-int-num'>1,496
</span><span class='per-decimals-dot'></span><span class='per-decimals'></span></span>
```

I tried to show this entire text by wrapping it with pre tag, but is didn't work.

```
<pre><span class='per-amount' role='text' aria-label='1,496 undefineds'><span class='per-curr'>₪
</span><span class='per-minus-sign'></span><span class='per-int-num'>1,496</span><span class='per-decimals-dot'></span><span class='per-decimals'></span></span></pre>
```

Is there a way to force the browser to show it, without using CSS?

Comment: It's pretty easy with JS, but I imagine you don't want that either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display HTML tags as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**xmp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp) instead of **pre**, but do note that it's deprecated since HTML3.2 and obsolete as of HTML5 – although it still seems to work in all major browsers:

```html
<xmp><span class='per-amount' role='text' aria-label='1,496 undefineds'><span class='per-curr'>₪
</span><span class='per-minus-sign'></span><span class='per-int-num'>1,496</span><span class='per-decimals-dot'></span><span class='per-decimals'></span></span></xmp>
```

Your other option would be to change less-thans to `&lt;`, but that could require preprocessing or JavaScript.

Comment: `xmp` isn't just deprecated, it's "obsolete". ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp)). the "obsolete" classification means the standards body is essentially telling browser vendors "please stop supporting this element entirely. it is detrimental to our standardizing efforts". (whereas "deprecated" means "developers should avoid using this, but browsers should still support it".)

Comment: Good point, @WoodrowBarlow, although I think it's unfortunate that it was removed from the spec.

Comment: although it was convenient, it creates fundamental ambiguities in the parsing grammar for HTML. it has been obsolete since HTML 3.2 and using it today will put browsers in [quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode), which can create difficult-to-diagnose rendering bugs on your webpage.

Comment: Very good point re ambiguities.  But do you have a reference that it actually puts browsers in quirks mode?

Comment: tbh, i made a bit of an assumption there. i just tested in ff, and apparently the mere presence of an `xmp` tag is _not_ enough to put the browser in quirks mode. it's possible that some more complex use cases would activate quirks mode, but i suppose i misspoke a little bit there. it does, however, fail validation ("Element `xmp` not allowed as child of element `body` in this context.")

Comment: Good to know.  I would say it's safe to use in most cases (presently), but with the caveats you've given.