How avoid cutting simple expression a<b in html sanitizer?
I am using package https://github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday
Please, help me, how to avoid sanitize simple expression a<b in string with HTML?
I want that after apply sanitize expression a<b remained in HTML text
This sanitizer delete all text to end of text or for first html tag
policy := bluemonday.NewPolicy() 
fmt.Println(html.UnescapeString(policy.Sanitize("{"key": "a<b"}")))

I want {"key": "a<b"} but getting simple {"key": "a
This is conversation by somebody
https://github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday/issues/79

If you're asking about Go code since you tagged this as go, you need to show some of the code. If you're just asking about html, you can't write < directly in html: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/how-to-display-raw-html-code-on-an-html-page, ...

No, I am asking about golang package
And thanks, I sown some of code

What are you expecting to happen? You are calling Sanitize, which is going to remove the invalid html, which is exactly what it does.

I edited my post and shown what I am expecting and what I am getting

a<b isn't valid html, so why are you trying to sanitize it? If that is within actual html you must use the correct html entities (see any of the linked answers).

Just example, I sanitize json and it can consist html
{"key": "a<img onerror='alert(1)'/>b", "k2": "a<b"}

That's javascript not html, so sanitizing it with an html sanitizer doesn't work. If it's in a script tag within html, you need to sanitize it with the proper html context.

Not, it is not script, it is json passed to server

Why are you expecting an html sanitizer to work on json? The solution seems to be just to not do that?

This is conversation by somebody
https://github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday/issues/79
