# Getting an invalid syntax error

Tags: python, mapreduce

Apologies in advance for what I know will be a simple problem. I'm a total beginner to Python, but have decided to use it to write a mapreduce doing sentiment analysis.

I have taken a python file from this link: http://www.alex-hanna.com/tworkshops/lesson-6-basic-sentiment-analysis/ to give me guidance and am trying to run it. The code for the particular thing I have problems with is:

```
…
if len(sys.argv) &lt; 2:
   print "Usage: avgNReduce.py "
   sys.exit(0)
…
```

The error is:

```
   if len(sys.argv) &lt; 2:
                       ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm assuming this is a basic problem to resolve, but despite googling it I don't really know how I'm meant to fix this. I've tried using a colon instead of a semi colon and have ensured the ampersand was correct from the copying over. Any ideas?

Comment: Did some website double encode, did it? You are looking for the `<` operator; `&lt;` is a HTML escape code for that character.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the `<` operator there instead of `lt`. (`lt` stands for the less than operator in HTML, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068951/what-do-lt-and-gt-stand-for) thread.)

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Usage: avgNReduce.py "
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did say I was a total beginner!

Comment: Glad to help. Happy Learning! And, feel free to accept the answer when the system allows you to. :)

Comment: It's literally `&lt;` on the page he [copied it from](http://www.alex-hanna.com/tworkshops/lesson-6-basic-sentiment-analysis/). I filed a "bug" with the author.

Comment: @msw : Yeah. The original author must have made some mistake. :P

Comment: Can I ask a quick follow up question then. From some basic reading I see that in the code I posted a dictionary, sentimentDict is created, with two keys that aren't mapped to any values. Later, two text files are opened and each line is stripped and mapped to these dictionaries. But what is the = 1 part for? Why is that necessary?

Comment: @AndrewMartin : I've not read the whole code, but maybe the author is trying to keep a dictionary with `positive` and `negative` sentiments both as empty dictionaries at first and mapping the lines in the text file to their occurrences (for counting the ratio). This assumes that each keyword occurs only once, since the author simply replaces the value if another occurrence is found (which may not be the case, since the files would already have only single keywords).

Comment: @SukritKalra That sounds very logical. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewMartin : Seeing the pseudo-code, I really don't find it as necessary, the author could have simply made a list of `positive` and `negative` words, though the looking up would be O(n), whereas it is O(1) in the dictionary.

Comment: @AndrewMartin I suggest you open a new question and tag it `nltk`as you'll it warrants its own question *and* you'll get more NLTK users looking at it.

Comment: @msw  Thanks, just did that