# What character encoding is &gt;?

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding

In HTML, you can write the greater than sign ">" as `&gt;`

and the less than symbol "<" as `&lt;`.

Is this encoding defined by the HTML encoding or some standard like ISO, UTF-xxx, BaseXXX, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do &lt; and &gt; stand for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068951/what-do-lt-and-gt-stand-for)

Comment: @Makoto That's dumb. I clearly stated what they stood for. The question was what the encoding was called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html) might answer your question. Basically it is HTML encoding for a few predefined characters.

Characters like `&gt;` and `&amp;` are `HTML Entities` specifically, they are `Named HTML Entities`

Comment: Thanks. So it's technically called "Character Entity". That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You'll hear it referred to as both though across the interwebs, so it's useful to know.

Comment: Most developers though will probably refer to it as an "encoding" and you'll find plenty of online tools that "encode" html and replace the ">" and "<" characters along with other characters.

Comment: Personally, I tend to call them "named entities". In reality, I rarely ever say them outloud and typically just know to use `&amp; &nbsp; &gt;` etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an encoding at all. Even informally, it is more often called “escape notation” or something like that, not an encoding.

Since the question seems to be just about the *name* of the construct, here are the correct terms:

- In SGML, which is what HTML is formally based on up to HTML 4.01, the term is “entity reference”. It so happens that all entities predefined in HTML expand each to a single character, and this is why they are often called “character references” or something like that, but that’s informal. Even HTML 4.01 calls them [“character references”](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.3), but normatively HTML 4.01 cites SGML, so that’s to be regarded as informal. In SGML, only notations that refer to characters by their code numbers, such as `&#62;`, are called character references.
- In XML, which is what XHTML is based on, the term is [“entity reference”](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references), too.
- In HTML5, the term is [“named character reference”](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references).

Answer (score 0):

They are defined by ISO.

This link will help:[Character_encodings_in_HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)

Comment: This is not relevant to OP’s question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph he asked "Is this encoding html encoding or some standard?" didn't asked "What do &lt; and &gt; stand for?"...So, my answer is more relavant than others to OP's question...why you are downvoting?

Comment: @user3830694 You are correct. That is exactly what I was asking. However, while the link you sent me was good, the simple and direct answer is what Ethan gave, which is "Character Entity".

Comment: @AndroidDev thanks..someone gave me a downvote on the answer even though I were right.