# I need some clarification on some code samples

Tags: dart

http://radar.oreilly.com/2013/05/dart-is-not-the-language-you-think-it-is.html

at the risk of asking a stupid question:

I have never seen this syntax before:

```Dart
// Dart
class Point {
  num x, y;
  Point(this.x, this.y);

  String toString() =&gt; 'X: $x, Y: $y';
}
```

is &gt indicating a reference?

```Dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class LoggingProxy {
  InstanceMirror mirror;
  LoggingProxy(delegate)
    : mirror = reflect(delegate);

  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    var name = invocation.memberName;
    print('${name} was called');
    return mirror.delegate(invocation);
  }
}
```

and what is the colon in:

```Dart
LoggingProxy(delegate)
  : mirror = reflect(delegate);
```

doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code has been escaped for some reason:

```dart
String toString() =&gt; 'X: $x, Y: $y';
```

[What do entities: &lt; and &gt; stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068951/what-do-lt-and-gt-stand-for)

It's simply `=>`  syntax shorthand for the function body that is equal to  `{return 'X: $x, Y: $y'; }`
Should be `String toString() => 'X: $x, Y: $y';` instead.

And this is [constructor's initializer list:](https://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-11.html)

```dart
LoggingProxy(delegate)
  : mirror = reflect(delegate);
```

Comment: #1 derp #2 ahh kinda the same thing but for a constructor?

Comment: @chrisgotter #2 for example, final fields cannot be initialized in the constructor's body. But, if they depends on constructor's arguments, you can use initializer list.