# How do you escape Greater than and Less than within the intelisence headers in visual studio?

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

If you are in the html comments for intellisense, what do you do to escape the symbols '<' and '>'?
It makes sense to me that intellisense returns an error for this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Compares two levels, where 
    /// given (a, b), 
    /// if a > b then returns a value greater then 0;
    /// if a < b then returns a value less then 0;
    /// if a == b then returns 0;
    /// </summary>
```

Comment: [`&lt;` and `&gt;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5068951)

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question. Do you think this is a true duplicate since there the answer is really the question and here the question is the answer? I'll defer to your wisdom.

Comment: The question is a different one.