# Non-valid code snippets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to make my website valid to past the school project. On my website there are few code snippets, which I implemented and when I check it on w3 validator, this error pops out: Named character reference was not terminated by a semicolon. (Or & should have been escaped as &.)

[This is the website](http://tomas-nosek.moxo.cz/navbar.html)

I don't quite understand the error message. Can someone explain?

```
<pre><code> <!-- Example of code (Carousel -->

       &ltdiv class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation"&gt
        &ltdiv class="container"&gt

           &ltbutton class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"&gt
              &ltspan class="icon-bar"&gt&lt/span&gt
              &ltspan class="icon-bar"&gt&lt/span&gt
              &ltspan class="icon-bar"&gt&lt/span&gt
           &lt/button&gt

           &lta class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"&gtFUTURE LOGO&lt/a&gt 
             &ltdiv class="visible-xs  clearfix"&gt&lt/div&gt


           &ltdiv class="navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse"&gt
              &ltul class="nav navbar-nav"&gt

                 &ltli&gt&lta href="index.html"&gt&ltspan class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"&gt&lt/span&gt Domu&lt/a&gt&lt/li&gt


                 &ltli&gt&lta href="obsahmp.html"&gtObsah MP&lt/a&gt&lt/li&gt

                 &ltli class="dropdown"&gt&lta href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"&gt
                 Responzivní webdesign&ltstrong class="caret"&gt&lt/strong&gt&lt/a&gt
                    &ltul class="dropdown-menu"&gt
                      &ltli&gt&lta href="responzivniwebdesign.html"&gtCo to vlastně je?&lt/a&gt&lt/li&gt
                      &ltli&gt&lta href="webovarozvrzeni.html"&gtWebová rozvržení&lt/a&gt&lt/li&gt
                      &ltli&gt&lta href="howto.html"&gtTvorba responzivního webu&lt/a&gt&lt/li&gt

                      &ltli class="divider"&gt&lt/li&gt

                      &ltli class="dropdown-header"&gtCSS frameworky&lt/li&gt
                      &ltli&gt&lta href="frameworky.html"&gtCo, jak a proč?&lt/a&gt&lt/li&gt
                      &ltli&gt&lta href="bootstrap.html"&gtTwitter bootstrap&lt/a&gt&lt/li&gt
                    &lt/ul&gt&lt!-- End dropdown-menu--&gt
                 &lt/li&gt&lt!-- End dropdown--&gt

                 &ltli class="dropdown active"&gt&lta href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"&gt
                 Použité komponenty&ltstrong class="caret"&gt&lt/strong&gt&lt/a&gt
                    &ltul class="dropdown-menu"&gt
                      &ltli&gt&lta href="navbar.html"&gtNavbar&lt/a&gt&lt/li&gt
                      &ltli&gt&lta href="carousel.html"&gtCarousel&lt/a&gt&lt/li&gt
                    &lt/ul&gt&lt!-- End dropdown-menu--&gt
                 &lt/li&gt&lt!-- End dropdown--&gt
              &lt/ul&gt&lt!--End nav--&gt
           &lt/div&gt&lt!-- End navbar-collapse--&gt
        &lt/div&gt &lt!-- End container--&gt
    &lt/div&gt &lt!-- End navbar--&gt



                </code></pre> <!-- End of example of code (Carousel -->
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: I implemented the code to the question @j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're displaying HTML syntax on your page, to do that you're using entities such as `&lt;` (which stands for [less than sign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5068965/5297207) `<`). Except in your code the `;` seems to be missing (just `&lt`) from all those entities, which is what the validator is complaining about.

When I copied your source into notepad and replaced all `&lt` and `&gt` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` the validator threw no errors.

(If the code you're trying to validate is actually the code **in** the code box, then you shouldn't be running the validation on the page...)

Comment: I need to validate the whole webpage, there is no need for the code in the box to be valid for me @Talya S

Comment: My answer stands then. You're replying to what I added as a parantheses in case I misunderstood- and I didn't.  The error is coming from how the code in the box is written to show up as code on your page. You use `&lt` to show a `<` sign, but the valid syntax is `&lt;`.