# java swing Document HTML Entities

Tags: java, html, swing

When I call the fuction `javax.swing.text.Document#insertString(...)` with a text containing a `<` i get something like `&lt;` rendered. The expected output would be `<`. Is there any way to manage that?

Comment: it gets Encoded that's why it appears as `&lt;`.

Comment: yeah, I see, but I want do render `<` as said... Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`&lt;` stands for the less-than sign `<` and `&gt;` stands for the greater-than sign `>`

[What do entities: &lt; and &gt; stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068951/what-do-entities-lt-and-gt-stand-for)

I think(not really sure) you can replace like

```
string.replaceAll("&l t;","<");
```

wish I could add comment, instead of answering but my reputation is not allowing me to do.