# when appending the </> text as html, it's not load into the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, innerhtml

I am trying to append the html in the DOM using innerHTML method. When </> content was inside the string html content which i want to append in DOM, It will not load in DOM. it's automatically removed.

ex:

```js
   document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "<div></></div>";


   console.log(document.getElementById("container").innerHTML);

   result:  "<div></div>"
```

I don't know why. Can anyone clarify this for me please.?

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Because `</>` isn't valid HTML? (At least that's my understanding... please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using `</>`?

Comment: I think your problem might be because you're trying to put `</>` inside a `<div></div>`. If you put other text instead of `</>` then your code should work, as long as you don't have any other syntax errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display HTML tags as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Comment: If you just want to put `</>` into the container, you could just do -> `innerText = '</>'`

Comment: What purpose would it serve to have it in there? A DOM node has children for which the docs say "Child nodes include elements, text and comments" ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)). Trying to add `</>` apparently resolves to neither of those three, and it seems to get discarded instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print `</>` as text inside HTML, use the respective HTML codes.

`<` = `&lt;` and `>` = `&gt;`:

```js
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "<div>&lt;/&gt;</div>";
console.log(_.escape('</>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

---

Common libraries like underscore/lodash has [`_.escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) method that'll do the conversion for you. See comment by @Keith below for a custom implementation.

Comment: For people that wanna know: `lt` means `lesser than` and `gt` means `greater than`

Comment: @Reyno it's `less than` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068951/what-do-lt-and-gt-stand-for  https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/821/55055

Comment: If you want to do the escape the html in code, you can use the DOM to do it for you..  eg.  `const escHtml = s => { const a = document.createElement('div'); a.innerText = s; return a.innerHTML; }`