# Azure Resource Graph Explorer :: Draw a trendline in the time chart

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, kql, azure-resource-graph

I was reading this [article](https://blog.developpez.com/mikedavem/p13208/sql-azure/finops-with-azure-cost-management-and-azure-log-analytics) about how to draw a trendline in the time chart related to the Azure SQL Database consumption.

The query is like this:

```
AzureMetrics
| where TimeGenerated &gt;= ago(90d)
| where Resource == 'MyDB'
| where MetricName == 'full_backup_size_bytes' // in ('full_backup_size_bytes','diff_backup_size_bytes','log_backup_size_bytes')
| make-series SizeBackupDiffTB=max(Maximum/1024/1024/1024/1024) on TimeGenerated in range(ago(90d),now(), 1d)
| extend (RSquare,Slope,Variance,RVariance,Interception,TrendLine)=series_fit_line(SizeBackupDiffTB)
| render timechart
```

But the Azure Portal returns this error:

```
Please provide below info when asking for support: timestamp = 2022-12-19T09:09:42.5539654Z, correlationId = 9cfa2a61-7cbe-412d-8e21-20b245a0e7da. (Code:BadRequest)

Details:
Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the Azure Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying. (Code:InvalidQuery)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
```

I think the problem might recide in the second line `&gt;=`.

But what does that means?

EDIT: I think there is more than one problem because it doesn't take `make-series` and `render timechart`:

[image]

But the error is now reduced:

```
Please provide below info when asking for support: timestamp = 2022-12-19T09:37:04.2221903Z, correlationId = 12157f78-2c92-4820-94d6-f088acf1a5a0. (Code:BadRequest)

Details:
Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the Azure Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying. (Code:InvalidQuery)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
More information on the error can be found here.
```

Comment: I think &gt;= stands for >=

Comment: Thank you, that might have fixed the problem. Now on line fife it doesn't recognize `make-series`. I think there are several errors with the query overall

Comment: Hum, it works in my lab. And it actually is something part of KQL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator. Where are you running this query ? From Log Analytics ?

Comment: I'm running it form Azure Resource Graph Explorer

Comment: This query has to be ran from Log Analytics. Resource Graph is meant to explorer resources, not metrics/logs, see respectively https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/queries and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the Unicode for [greater-than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068951/what-do-lt-and-gt-stand-for) that is not reflected properly. You should try with the following in Log Analytics:

```
AzureMetrics
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(90d)
| where Resource == 'MyDB'
| where MetricName == 'full_backup_size_bytes' // in ('full_backup_size_bytes','diff_backup_size_bytes','log_backup_size_bytes')
| make-series SizeBackupDiffTB=max(Maximum/1024/1024/1024/1024) on TimeGenerated in range(ago(90d),now(), 1d)
| extend (RSquare,Slope,Variance,RVariance,Interception,TrendLine)=series_fit_line(SizeBackupDiffTB)
| render timechart
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help. I have added a few more info. Is it working on your end? Are you targeting the name of an Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Resource Graph only supports a subset of KQL, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/query-language#supported-kql-language-elements. You need to run this query in Log Analytics to get the full breadth of the query language, including make-series and rendering.