# Why is <br> an element, not an entity?

Tags: html, w3c, line-breaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is <br> an HTML element rather than an HTML entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488198/why-is-br-an-html-element-rather-than-an-html-entity)

Why is a line break in HTML an element `<br>` instead of an entity, such as `&br;`? In many ways it seems a bad fit to be an element (e.g. has a different node type attribute to normal HTML elements, is similar to `&nbsp;` in what it does).

Comment: Because in some cases you may want to disable line breaks and make everything appear a single line. can't dynamically remap a `&nbsp;` to something else, but you CAN use css to make a `<br>` not do a line break.

Comment: in that case, let me rephrase my question: Why is &nbsp; not a tag? :)

Comment: Another thing I can think of: compatibility. &br; seems to indicate a single character but \r\n is the right sequence on Windoze, \n for Linux, \r for old Mac OSes. A non-breaking space character, however, has the same meaning on all systems (and is a single code point).

Comment: Just for trivia, RFC 1866, the HTML 2.0 spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt

Comment: Even the rephrased question assumes they thought this sort of thing through back then.

Comment: HTML entities correspond to Unicode code points. You can't just make up a random entity; you have to get it added to Unicode. Unicode has various code points for line break, but HTML treats whitespace as space (except under special conditions). If you want U+000d to be a hard line break, then that forces you to make all your paragraphs one long line, which is unwieldy.

Comment: @Borealid, this is probably the answer (I suspected as much before asking, but thought I'd check out of curiosity). Those manic sultanas get everywhere. I may suggest to W3C that they add a &br; entity to the spec and move to deprecate <br>.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-br-element)*

> The br element represents a line break.
>
> While line breaks are usually represented in visual media by
>   physically moving subsequent text to a new line, a style sheet or user
>   agent would be equally justified in causing line breaks to be rendered
>   in a different manner, for instance as green dots, or as extra
>   spacing.
>
> br elements must be used only for line breaks that are actually part
>   of the content, as in poems or addresses.

So it states clearly that it is ok to style a line break as something else, thus justifying why it's not an entity. It does make me think that there should be two ways of adding a line break - as an entity `&br;` or a tag `<br>`, thus giving the author flexibility over whether the line break is stylable or not. The statement above - equating use of line breaks in poems and addresses - is a bit of a broad brush if you ask me.

*Not sure if it's *the* spec, but it's certainly *a* spec

Comment: And this should happen how? By magic? What would `&br;` be expanded to in the DTD that would display as a line-break?

Answer (score 10):

Whitespace in HTML is rendered as a one character space regardless of the amount of whitespace. This assists in markup authorship without impacting the markup rendering.

<br/> is not a display character, but a formatting specifier for when the format affects the content's meaning. The HTML 5 spec states that it "must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content, as in poems or addresses."

Comment: Great explanation. The `<br>` element *is* widely misused for layout purposes (for example, people using `<br><br>` instead of paragraphs).

Comment: I still don't quite see why this means it has to be a tag when &nbsp; isn't. As someone commented above, if you wanted to you could style a <br> to display none with CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/XqdKE/), thus altering the content's meaning. I know that technically this doesn't change the meaning as a change in CSS isn't a change in markup, but if a br is supposed to have intrinsic meaning dependent on it being a new line it seems wrong that it should be mutable in this way.

Comment: @wheresrhys - I agree. On the basis of `<br>`s modern semantics, it's doubtful whether it would have been invented. We might have been expected to use U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR instead, which could been mapped to `&br;`. But HTML's design is rarely clear cut. History and convenience play a large part (`<br>` works no matter what the character set is, for example), and unless you can see a real-world problem with the way things currently are, it's best just to accept it and go with it.

Comment: @wheresrhys `&nbsp;` gets replaced with ' '. What character or set of characters would you suggest replacing `&br;` with?

Comment: @Alohci U+2028 is whitespace, so it is folded in HTML source, the same as space, tabs, and other new-line characters. If `&br;` was mapped to U+2028 it would have no difference than if we'd mapped it to space or tab. We need `<br>` because it affects the rendering on the screen.

Comment: @JonHanna - That's exactly why we don't need `<br>`. That would make it a presentational element. All other such elements have been obsoleted in HTML5 in favour of CSS. If `<br>` carried no semantics at all, it would have been obsoleted too.

Comment: @Alohci firstly, "line break here" does have semantics. Secondly, what would you suggest should be done for people who want to have a line-break somewhere?

Comment: @JonHanna - The semantics of a line break are the same as U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR. The rendering is different, but that's a CSS issue. There's lots of ways to start a new line in CSS. `display:block`, `<span style="white-space:pre">&#10;</span>` etc., Just pick the appropriate one. Not marking up addresses or poetry, I haven't used a `<br>` tag for years.

Comment: @Alohci Since you concede that U+2028 has semantics, and since we obviously can't use U+2028 in the source to convey that those semantics should exist in the output, having an element is the logical answer. `<br>` is over-used, but over-used is not the same as unnecessary.