# Is there a security leak using htmlspecialchars and not encoding &?

Tags: php, html, security

I'm currently using the following line in one of my projects:

```
htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

Thus it encodes &, ', ", <,> . 
My question there is (as for some internal coding reasons I'm contemplating it) there any security risk involved with not encoding & ?
Thus if using the following line would generate a security risk/leak:

```
$value=str_replace('&amp;','&',$value);
```

*For <,>,'," it is perfectly clear to me WHY they should be encoded as they could be used for html injection. But & I don't see a reason (nor did I find any special reason there so far).*

**EDIT:**

As database access was mentioned a few times. I'm using doctrine there with parameters,... so the database should be (relatively) save from SQL injections.

The above conversion was solely made to prevent html injections, but currently as most of the data lands in fields created by extJS,... the "&" conversion gets in the way there as in the textfield `&amp;` is displayed instead of `&`.

Sadly because of an architectural error I can only do the whole htmlspecialchars and str_replace part at one and only one location (if I do it at all). And there I can't differentate. Thus also my question there in regards to the `&`.

Comment: Replacing `&` with `&amp;` prevents users from inserting character entities like `&nbsp;`. Although that isn't a security issue. `htmlspecialchars()` just escapes text so that it is displayed exactly the way it is written.

Comment: I edited your question, and the edit basically showed the problem that occurs when not escaping `&`: you wrote »[…] in the textfield "`&amp;`" is displayed instead of "`&`"« – which, when rendered, displayed as »[…] in the textfield "`&`" is displayed instead of "`&`"« (So, in the rendered output, you could not see a difference and it made me wonder …)

Comment: Thank you. Sadly I have the tendency to create sentences so complicated that I stumble over my own feet there.
It was meant as it stands now (thanks again).
In the textfield "&amp;" is displayed instead of "&"  If it was outside a textfield it would be automatically converted to "&" but so (inside the textfield) it stays as "&amp;"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a security risk in leaving ampersands unescaped in user-submitted data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027167/is-there-a-security-risk-in-leaving-ampersands-unescaped-in-user-submitted-data)

Comment: @Gumbo In Ulm, um Ulm, um Ulm herum. :D

Answer (score 4):

There exists a security risk whenever you accept user input and then proceed to evaluate it as an expression, output it back to the web page or inject it directly into a SQL statement. `htmlspecialchars` encodes some (not all) characters that could be used for nefarious purposes--such as single quotes and double quotes used in SQL injection attacks. `htmlspecialchars` shouldn't be used for input security. You should use sophisticated purpose-built methods for removing, encoding or escaping potentially unsafe characters. There are all kinds of special characters and [filter evasion techniques](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAB&url=https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet&ei=sELeUPz-BaOpiQLn1ICABw&usg=AFQjCNGpwRvD1Umo4RWraEaODQ6jydCbgA&sig2=-fvC8YPt-RBRzhJJos_CSg&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.cGE) that `htmlspecialchars` doesn't account for (e.g., IE6 and US-ASCII). Personally, I prefer to remove any special characters if they're not appropriate input (JavaScript to remove non-alphanumeric input: `input = input.replace(/\W/g, '');`).

It is always important to sanitize/escape your user input on the client-side using JavaScript, avoid evaluating user input as expressions, and use prepared statements (e.g., PDO) for SQL actions.

If we could see more of your application, we'd be able to better tell if you have a security issue.

Comment: For SQL injection prevention, one uses `mysql_real_escape_query` (or similar database-dependent function) or PDO, not `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Yep, exactly, answer already updated. Though I wouldn't use `mysql_real_escape_query` it's deprecated as of PHP5.5.

Comment: I updated my post there. I'm using doctrine for the database layer so sql injection should not be a problem there. My only concern there is the possibility of html injection.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any security risk involved with not encoding `&` ?

There is a security risk for anyone still running a Netscape 4-based browser, where `&{...}` in attributes is a backdoor method to run JS. Hopefully you don't have any Netscape users today, but who knows how some wacky future browser might parse malformed HTML...

There is a functionality risk in that escaping `&` is definitively the right thing for HTML markup and not escaping it can mangle your output. eg. markup=`cut&copy&paste`, output=`cut©&paste`.

> currently as most of the data lands in fields created by extJS,... the "&" conversion gets in the way there as in the textfield & is displayed instead of &.

That is a different error - you should find and fix that, rather than trying to work around the problem. How are you creating the fields, and getting the data into the code that creates them?

If you are injecting values into JavaScript variables then you need to be JS-escaping them, not HTML-escaping them; the two contexts require different handling. A potential workaround is to hide data in the document HTML content (commonly in `data-` attributes) and read it from there in JS.

Comment: +1 for "_If you are injecting values into JavaScript variables then you need to be JS-escaping them, not HTML-escaping them_."  That's the correct answer here.

Comment: Ps. For JS-escaping data in PHP, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines).

Comment: @Ilmari: From what I see the variant used in that question is using json_encode to encode and thus secure the data.
(currently it is handled so that I send the data from php json encoded to extJS which decodes it and represents the data [either on screen, or as grid coloumn names or as data in fields depending on the location]). Would it also be needed still to encode it there again?

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars` doesn't have anything to do with security, but with HTML specification that says that those characters are special. For security, there are other kinds of escapes - specifically, the important one is the escaping that happens right before things are inserted into a database, but that's not what `htmlspecialchars` is used for.

You would use `htmlspecialchars` whenever you want to output HTML text, such as

```
<div id="here" class='here'> or here </div>
```

The reason for this is that if the first `here` contained a literal quote, you'd get a syntax error in your HTML; same with the second `here` and the double quote, or third `here` and a less-than symbol. Greater-than symbol is not as dangerous, I think, but is replaced for balance (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Ampersand is replaced so that if someone wanted to display `&quot;`, not escaping it would display `"` instead. When you properly `htmlspecialchars` it, you will get `&amp;quot;` in HTML, which will render to the desired `&quot;`.

As Blender says, it's so that text looks like you want it to. Nothing to do with security.

EDIT: Or rather, it could do with HTML-security (just occured to me). Say someone replaced the first `here` with `"><script src="http://malicio.us/code"/><p id="`... If it was properly escaped, nothing happens, it's just that weird piece of text inside the attribute. But if not... Still, nothing to do with SQL security, at least.

Comment: Although as the <  and the " and > would still be encoded (even if & itself is not) not encoding & shouldn't affect the encoding and thus the elimination of the risk that injection attempt poses.

Comment: Yup. As I said, it's primary purpose is not breaking HTML syntax when inserting text into it. I can't think of a scenario where not encoding `&` would lead to security problems. Still, me not being able to think of something doesn't mean it's impossible :P

Comment: Same here. That is why I created the question :)  But at least it is reassuring that I'm not the only one who doesn't see a risk there.